# Need two services that share database in Tomcat 9

Tags: database, tomcat, configuration

I would like to run two tomcat services on two ports (8080,8181) with different codeBases, but sharing the same database resource. When I do this, I get "javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [comp/env/jdbc/mydb] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [comp]." when it tries to initialize the second Service.

My Services look like this in the server.xml:

```xml
  ...
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource auth="Container" name="jdbc/mydb" url="jdbc:db2://myserver:50000/mydb" username="xxx" password="xxx" .... />           
  </GlobalNamingResources>
...
 <Service name="Catalina8080">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
....
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps8080" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" .... />
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
 <Service name="Catalina8181">
    <Connector port="8181" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8444" />
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
....
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps8181" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" .... />
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
```

My server level context file looks like :

```xml
<Context>
...
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/mydb" global="jdbc/mydb" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</Context>
```

I've tried adding and removing the Resource links at the application level context file, but nothing seems to change the outcome. Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **change the name** of your `<Engine>` in the second service: there can be only one naming context for each combination of *engine name*, *host name* and *context name*.

In your case the combination (`Catalina`, `localhost`, your application name) probably appears twice, hence you should be able to find an entry like this:

```
SEVERE [main] naming.namingContextCreationFailed
```

in the logs and JNDI doesn't work in the second context.